# Next js Error "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <div>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mobx, tailwind-css

I have a Dark Mode component which is a simple toggle between Sun & Moon icons.

## DarkMode.tsx

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import { MoonIcon, SunIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

import { useStore } from '@/store/index'

export const DarkMode = observer(() => {
    const { theme, setTheme, isPersisting } = useStore()

    if (!isPersisting) return null

    return (
        <>
            {theme === 'dark' && (
                <button
                    className="fixed bottom-12 right-12 focus:outline-none"
                    title="Activate light mode"
                    onClick={() => {
                        setTheme('light')
                    }}
                >
                    <MoonIcon className="w-8 h-8" />
                </button>
            )}
            {theme === 'light' && (
                <button
                    className="fixed bottom-12 right-12 focus:outline-none"
                    title="Activate dark mode"
                    onClick={() => {
                        setTheme('dark')
                    }}
                >
                    <SunIcon className="w-8 h-8" />
                </button>
            )}
        </>
    )
})
```

I am using MobX to track my `theme` & `mobx-persist-store` to persist the data in `localStorage`.

## store.ts

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action } from 'mobx'
import { makePersistable, isPersisting, clearPersistedStore } from 'mobx-persist-store'

import type { Theme, IStore } from '@/types/index'

const name = 'Store'
const IS_SERVER = typeof window === 'undefined'

export class Store implements IStore {
    theme: Theme = 'light'

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            theme: observable,
            setTheme: action.bound,
            reset: action.bound,
        })

        if (!IS_SERVER) {
            makePersistable(this, { name, properties: ['theme'], storage: window.localStorage })
        }
    }

    setTheme(theme: Theme) {
        this.theme = theme
    }

    get isPersisting() {
        return isPersisting(this)
    }

    async reset() {
        if (!IS_SERVER) await clearPersistedStore(this)
    }
}
```

And I am adding `dark` class to `html` when the user selectes `dark` theme in Dark Mode component.

## _app.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import useSystemTheme from 'use-system-theme'

import { useStore } from '@/store/index'

import '@/components/NProgress'

import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'
import '@/styles/index.css'

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
    const systemTheme = useSystemTheme()
    const { theme, setTheme } = useStore()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const isDarkTheme = theme === 'dark' || (systemTheme === 'dark' && theme !== 'light')
        if (isDarkTheme) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
            setTheme('dark')
        } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
            setTheme('light')
        }
    }, [theme, systemTheme])

    return (
        <>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}

export default observer(MyApp)
```

I am still getting an error that says:

```sh
VM356 main.js:16820 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <div>.
    at button
    at wrappedComponent (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1624277701361:2690:73)
    at Nav (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/tutorial/the-complete-guide-to-starting-a-blog-in-nextjs-and-mdx.js?ts=1624277701361:12454:23)
    at Tutorial (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/tutorial/the-complete-guide-to-starting-a-blog-in-nextjs-and-mdx.js?ts=1624277701361:12973:24)
    at MDXLayout
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/tutorial/the-complete-guide-to-starting-a-blog-in-nextjs-and-mdx.js?ts=1624277701361:7880:30
    at MDXContent (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/tutorial/the-complete-guide-to-starting-a-blog-in-nextjs-and-mdx.js?ts=1624277701361:22563:25)
    at wrappedComponent (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1624277701361:2690:73)
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1624277701361:767:47)
    at ReactDevOverlay (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1624277701361:883:23)
    at Container (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1624277701361:8756:5)
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1624277701361:9244:24)
    at Root (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1624277701361:9380:25)
```

The `button`'s `onClick` event handler disappears from the DOM itself.

Funny thing is it used to work on MacOS but not on Windows. I cloned the same project. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece of the puzzle was I had wrapped my `Nav` outside of `ThemeProvider`.

`Nav` contained `DarkMode` so it couldn't access `ThemeProvider`. My `_document.tsx` looked like:

```
<Nav />
<ThemeProvider attribute="class" themes={['light', 'dark']}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
</ThemeProvider>
```

So I had to bring that `Nav` inside `ThemeProvider` to get it working.

```
<ThemeProvider attribute="class" themes={['light', 'dark']}>
    <Nav />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with original question though, going to be misleading. By moving `Nav` inside `Provider` you won't get rid of html mismatch error

Comment: @Danila I know. But this was the main error which got solved by putting it inside. Sometimes some errors happen because of other errors.

Comment: Lol. It's funny the first answer solved the hydration error and this one actually fixed the light toggle issue.

Answer (score 6):

I has the same issue during dark/light theme implementation, but solved it based on [deadcoder0904](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6141587/deadcoder0904)'s comment.
In my case, the app was built using `next-themes` library.
As this error is related to SSR, it's needed to confirm the component is mounted on the frontend side.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';

const ThemeToggler = () => {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme()
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => setHasMounted(true));
  
  // this line is the key to avoid the error.
  if (!hasMounted) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      The current theme is: {theme}
      <button onClick={() => setTheme('light')}>Light Mode</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTheme('dark')}>Dark Mode</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThemeToggler;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

On the server your `DarkMode` component does not render anything (because `isPersisting` is false). And then on the client it renders something on the first pass (`isPersisting` becomes true on the client render) and that is why React (not Next.js) complains that markup between SSR and CSR does not match.

Basically it means that you always need to render some theme with SSR, but SSR does not know about `localStorage` so it can only pick the default value. And then correct value will be picked from `localStorage` after client render.

If you want to render correct theme with SSR without flashing of old theme or without errors like that one then you need to store it in cookies.

Comment: I understand the issue & I tried following the solution here https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#the-solution but I can't get the `button`'s `onClick` to work. The DOM strips of `onClick` completely. How do I get the `button`'s `onClick` to show up? Can you show an example code?

Comment: Show up where? What do you mean by "strips"?

Comment: By strip, I mean it removes the `onClick` handler so my `button` becomes `<button class="fixed bottom-12 right-12 focus:outline-none" title="Activate dark mode"></button>` in Windows. I used the same code on my Mac (which has been damaged forever now) & it worked. The website I linked has the solution using `hasMounted` hook which I think is right but I can't toggle any `button` as there is no `onClick` in the DOM.

Comment: Are you checking it with browser devtools? It's totally fine that there is no click handlers there

Comment: Yes, I'm checking with dev tools. Damn. TIL. But `console.log` doesn't show up either.

Comment: I'm afraid you would need to make reproduction on Codesandbox, can't help here without the code

Comment: Danila, I had kept the `Nav` outside the `ThemeProvider` so clicks weren't working either. Just added an answer :)