# "Warning: Prop `className` did not match" while using useDarkMode hook with css-modules in next.js project

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, server-side-rendering, css-modules

**My app works fine and toggle between light and dark theme perfectly if I initialize useDarkMode hook with true**, but it breaks and shows a warning if I pass **false** or nothing as a parameter.

```
import styles from './Header.module.scss'
import useDarkMode from "use-dark-mode";
const Header = () => {
    const darkMode = useDarkMode(false);
    console.log(darkMode.value)
    return (
      <div className={`${styles.main} ${darkMode.value && styles.darkMode}`}>
        
      </div>
    );
}
```

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "Header_main__xMA-0 false" Client: "Header_main__xMA-0 Header_darkMode__2dc2c"
```

I understand from server useDarkMode is getting initialized with false but client-side it's getting updated to true for os level dark selection, and I am not able to figure a way out of this.

It would be a great help if anyone can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next js Error "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <div>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068186/next-js-error-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-button-in)

Comment: I understand why it is not working, I am looking for any way around by using only **useDarkMode** hook and **css-modules** is it's really possible.

Comment: No, it is not. You will always have mismatch between server and client unless you use cookies (to detect what mode you need to render on the server).